# Should I substract imagenet pretrained inception_v3 model mean value at inception_v3.py keras?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, theano

```
def preprocess_input(x):
x /= 255.
x -= 0.5
x *= 2.
return x
```

I am using **keras** inception_v3 imagenet pretrained model([inception_v3.py](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/inception_v3.py)) to finetune on my own dataset.
 When I want to **subtract the imagenet mean value [123.68, 116.779, 103.939] and reverse axis RGB to BGR** as we often do, I find that the author provided a _preprocess_input()_ function at the end.I am confused about this.

Should I use the provided function *preprocess_input()* **or** subtract mean value and reverse axis as usual?
  Thanks lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in a original [Inception](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~wliu/papers/GoogLeNet.pdf) paper the autors mention as a data preprocessor the function you provided (one which is zero-centering all channels and resizes it to `[-1, 1]` interval). As in [InceptionV3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567) paper no new data transformation is provided I think that you may assume that you should use the following function:

```
def preprocess_input(x):
    x /= 255.
    x -= 0.5
    x *= 2.
    return x
```

Comment: I have read Inception paper "Going Deeper with Convolutions", but I didn't see such preprocessor function, can you give me more details?

Comment: Actually - it's not mentioned directly. But it's written in a part where they mentioned about zero-centered RGB channels. Squashing your input to [-1, 1] is an often transformation in this case.